# django - how to config a dynamic url

Tags: django

I have two page which display item summary and item detail info respectively.
the url.py like this:

```
(r'^summary/$', 'views.summary'),
(r'^summary_\d|[a-z]{24}$', 'views.itemInfo'),
```

The `summary.html` can query a item by id then jump to `summary_{{itemId}}.html` to display the item detail information. The itemId is mongodb ObjectId, then I use regex '`\d|[a-z]{24}`'.

In `summary.html` template I write:

```
<form action="???" method="post">
    query Item by id:
    <input type="text" name="itemId" value="" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="query" />
</form>
```

My problems:

1. What should I write in '???' place, the url to go is dynamic formed.
2. How I name the template `file(summary_{{itemId}}.html` which used to displaying item info?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your url first to grab the `id` from the url:

```
(r'^summary/(?P<id>\d|[a-z]{24})/$', 'views.itemInfo', name="item_info"),
```

Put the same summary url in form action

```
action="{% url 'views.summary' %}"
```

In summary view check if request is a `POST` request then grab the id and redirect to the detail view else if request is `GET` or no `id` found in `POST` show summary view again:

```
def summary(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST.get('itemId')
        if id:
            return redirect(reverse('item_info', kwargs={'id': id}))
    return render_to_response(
        'summary.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The detail view should query the item by id and pass the item in context. You just name your template as `item_detail.html` and pass the object instance to show different items by using single template:

```
def itemInfo(request, id):
    item = MyItemModel.objects.get(id=id)
    return render_to_response(
        'item_detail.html', {'item': item}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now play with `item` in `item_detail.html`.

Hope this helps you. Please take care of the `imports` your self.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two important things: URLs and data passing methods (POST, GET, etc.). HTTP isn't made to receive data such as what you planned to do using its URLs and frameworks (such as Django) will work against you if you persist going this way.

You should only have one page, namely /summary/. It should link to a view which checks if you have received an itemId in your POST data (if you keep your current HTML snippet). If not, only show the query form. Otherwise, add a div element which displays its data accordingly using template tags or filters. The built-in `if` [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if) could be of use.

As an added bonus, your search form will still be available when an entry is entered and you will have less code to maintain.

I would recommend switching to the GET method, which is meant to do what you want. It will allow users that bookmark entries on your website to keep their reference to the item and not only the search form.

Comment: Use only one page, the url.py will be "(r'^summary/$', 'views.summary'), (r'^summary/$', 'views.query'), " the second handler  'views.query' will not be called. How to solve this?

Comment: You should only have a single view in your case. In this view, you can have a conditional statement on the [querydict object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/) of the HttpRequest parameter passed to your view. For instance, along the lines of: " if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST and 'itemId' in request.POST: " would allow you to split your view in two.